# Is it possible to genrate labels form a number in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So i want to finalize my project Pyssword (https://github.com/RedCoderX/Pyssword) and set a Tkinter inteface. is it possible to generate number of labels from a variable ?

Comment: In short yes its possible to generate lables from a variable.
What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Also please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of a link.

Comment: How do you wish the labels are displayed? Any code you can show us? Otherwise it's not possible for us to answer your question. So give us more details. Do you want the text to be a number or 5 Labels if your variable is 5? Or something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpreted your question in two different ways. The first one is that you want to make a label with a number as text. This works:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
WindowMaster = Tk()
Label(master=WindowMaster, text=str(NumberVar)).pack()
```

The other way I interpreted your question is that you want to make (e.g. 5 Labels if your variable is 5). This works too:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
WindowMaster = Tk()
for i in range(NumberVar):
    Label(master=WindowMaster, text='lorem ipsum').pack()
```

Hope that helped.